# Create sequential number given two variables

Tags: r, plyr

I have a `data.frame`that looks similar to this one:

```
pp <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,3), zing=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"))

pp

a   zing  
1   a     
1   b     
1   c     
2   d     
2   e     
3   f
```

And I'd like to count the "uniqueness" of the variable `zing` given `a`. As a result, my data.frame should look like this:

```
a   zing  nr
1   a     1
1   b     2
1   c     3
2   d     1
2   e     2
3   f     1
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `q` is also the function for exiting R, I'd suggest you use another name for your variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
q <- transform(q, nr = ave(a, a, FUN = seq_along))
```

Comment: How would the command change if `pp` would change to `pp <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,3), zing=c("a", "a", "c", "d", "e", "f"))` and `nr` should look like this `nr=c(1,1,3,1,2,1)` ?

Comment: You could define `count <- function(x) with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))` and then run `transform(pp, nr = ave(as.integer(zing), a, FUN = count))`.

Comment: Try `pp %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(nr=min_rank(zing))`

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `getanID` from `splitstackshape`

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 getanID(pp,'a')
 #   a zing .id
 #1: 1    a   1
 #2: 1    b   2
 #3: 1    c   3
 #4: 2    d   1
 #5: 2    e   2
 #6: 3    f   1
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
##
q <- data.frame(
  a=c(1,1,1,2,2,3), 
  zing=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
  stringsAsFactors=F)
setDT(q)
##
q[,nr:=1:.N,by=a]
##
> q
   a zing nr
1: 1    a  1
2: 1    b  2
3: 1    c  3
4: 2    d  1
5: 2    e  2
6: 3    f  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
pp %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(nr = row_number())
```

dplyr and data.table will both be more efficient than `ave` if you're working on large data sets. If the data is not that large, you might not need those packages.